# Masstransit SQS AutoDelete not working for bus control queues

Tags: amazon-sqs, masstransit

Bus is configured like this:

```
services.AddMassTransit(x =>
    {
        x.UsingAmazonSqs((context, cfg) =>
        {
            cfg.Durable = true;
            cfg.AutoDelete = true;

            cfg.Host("us-east-2", h =>
            {
            });
        });
    });
```

I use request/response as well as send/receive. Each time my program is started, a new queue with "bus" in the name is created and stays there even after program is exited.
Is this by design?

Answer (score 0):

Amazon SQS does not have the concept of a temporary queue. Therefore, in order to remove the bus queue, the bus must be stopped. Typically this is done by the MassTransit Hosted Service when the process exits (SIGTERM, whatever). If the bus is not stopped, however, the queue will remain and must be manually cleaned up.

The other option, assuming you have a single service instance (bus endpoint queues cannot be shared or request responses may be picked up by the wrong instance), is to force the same queue name for the bus endpoint:

```cs
cfg.OverrideDefaultBusEndpointQueueName("some-name-here");
```

Comment: I'm using MassTransit Hosted Service, not sure why the queue is not cleaned up, MT version 7.3.0. My apps will have many instances so the 2nd option won't work.

Comment: Well, make sure the instance is being cleanly shut down instead of killed.